# Why cmd throws C:\Program cannot be found even I have quotes around the path?

Tags: windows, cmd

What I did is:

on windows, press "Windows" button, which brings up the start menu. I start typing:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\my.exe" -c "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\data.conf" -cert "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\my.key"
```

However when the cmd prompt shows up, it says:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Not sure why this is giving me error, as I have quotes around the path already. It may be just something stupid but 2nd pair of eyes is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the following description from `cmd /?`

> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last
>      quote character on the command line, preserving any text after the
>      last quote character.

your line should be corrected to:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\my\my.exe" -c "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\data.conf" -cert "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\my.key""
```

(which basically is `"cmd.exe" /k "command using "quoted parts""` (quoted string(s) inside a quoted expression)

Note: instead of `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"` you also can (should) use `"%comspec%"`

Comment: I recommend using the `/s` option to ensure that the outer quotes are stripped, especially if you're constructing the command line in software.  It saves you figuring out whether the command line meets the other criteria or not.

Answer (score 1):

Double quote characters are only handled properly by cmd when there are only two on a line.  Remove everything up to and including "/k" from what you typed and run the result - it worked for me in a similar scenario.  Note that you can save what you type to a .bat file and run that instead to save repeated typing (or repeated pasting).

The evidence can be found at http://www.computerhope.com/cmd.htm or if you run:

```
cmd /?
```

You'll see the following:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after the
switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is used to
process quote (") characters:

1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters on 
the command line are preserved:    
 - no /S switch
 - exactly two quote characters
 - no special characters between the two quote characters, where special is
   one of: &<>()@^|
 - there are one or more whitespace characters between the two quote
   characters
 - the string between the two quote characters is the name of an executable
   file.

2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote
character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last quote
character on the command line, preserving any text after the last quote
character.
```

Comment: I've got the disadvantage of working on a non-english Windows version. The resulting line would be `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\my\my.exe" -c "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\data.conf" -cert "C:\Program Files (x86)\my\my.key""`

Comment: @Stephan you are correct - I think you should put this into a new answer instead of a comment.